# Big 0 notation for duplicate function, C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, duplicates, big-o

What is the Big 0 notation for the function description in the screenshot.

It would take O(n) to go through all the numbers but once it finds the numbers and removes them what would that be? Would the removed parts be a constant A? and then would the function have to iterate through the numbers again?

This is what I am thinking for Big O

T(n) = n + a + (n-a) or something involving having to iterate through (n-a) number of steps after the first duplicate is found, then would big O be O(n)?

[image: Duplicate Function Description]

Comment: Please post text as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2):

Big O notation is considering the worst case. Let's say we need to remove all duplicates from the array `A=[1..n]`. The algorithm will start with the first element and check every remaining element - there are `n-1` of them. Since all values happen to be different it won't remove any from the array.

Next, the algorithm selects the second element and checks the remaining `n-2` elements in the array. And so on.

When the algorithm arrives at the final element it is done. The total number of comparisions is the sum of `(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0`. Through the power of maths, this sum becomes `(n-1)*n/2` and the dominating term is `n^2` so the algorithm is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: at the end where it is "+2 +1 +0" what is causing that?

Comment: @user2076774 For example, say the array is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. When the algorithm selects `5` it has to check the 2 remaining elements `6` and `7`. When it selects `6` it has to check the single remaining element. Finally, when it selects `7`, there are no more elements to check; thus 2+1+0 for the final 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is `O(n^2)`. Because for each element in the array you are iterating over the array and counting the occurrences of that element.

```
foreach item in array
    count = 0
    foreach other in array
         if item == other
             count += 1
    if count > 1
         remove item
```

As you see there are two nested loops in this algorithm which results in `O(n*n)`.
Removed items doesn't affect the worst case. Consider an array containing unique elements. No elements is being removed in this array.

**Note**: A naive implementation of this algorithm could result in `O(n^3)` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You started with first element you will go through all elements in the vector thats n-1 you will do that for n time its (n * n-1)/2 for worst case n time is the best case (all elements are 4)